# Java heap break up sum is not equal to total heap capacity

Tags: java, heap-memory

I have a Netty process running with 8 GB heap using Parallel GC with 4 thread(s). I am trying to analyze the heap and observed sum of all the capacity shown in the `jmap` is not even close to the 8 GB, Old Gen is just 1.5 GB and Young Gen is 750 MB.

Below is the output of **jmap -heap 7595**

```
Attaching to process ID 7595, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.131-b11

using thread-local object allocation.
Parallel GC with 4 thread(s)

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio         = 30
   MaxHeapFreeRatio         = 70
   MaxHeapSize              = 8589934592 (8192.0MB)
   NewSize                  = 88080384 (84.0MB)
   MaxNewSize               = 2863136768 (2730.5MB)
   OldSize                  = 176160768 (168.0MB)
   NewRatio                 = 2
   SurvivorRatio            = 8
   MetaspaceSize            = 21807104 (20.796875MB)
   CompressedClassSpaceSize = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   MaxMetaspaceSize         = 17592186044415 MB
   G1HeapRegionSize         = 0 (0.0MB)

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 763363328 (728.0MB)
   used     = 418551600 (399.1619110107422MB)
   free     = 344811728 (328.8380889892578MB)
   54.8299328311459% used
From Space:
   capacity = 1048576 (1.0MB)
   used     = 458752 (0.4375MB)
   free     = 589824 (0.5625MB)
   43.75% used
To Space:
   capacity = 1048576 (1.0MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 1048576 (1.0MB)
   0.0% used
PS Old Generation
   capacity = 1530396672 (1459.5MB)
   used     = 1196099760 (1140.6896209716797MB)
   free     = 334296912 (318.8103790283203MB)
   78.15619191309898% used

27146 interned Strings occupying 3164408 bytes.
```

[Young Gen Capacity(728) + Old Gen Capacity(1459) = 2187 MB] << 8GB

Comment: Netty uses native code, this code allocates memory outside of java managed heap (which is simply a memory block inside native java process heap). You can try actually decrease JVM heap memory, so that native code will have more memory available.

Answer (score 1):

By default JVM won't allocate the maximum heap after startup, instead a smaller initial heap will be allocated and expanded when JVM needs it. You can force the initial heap size to be 8GB by using `-Xms` flag e.g. `-Xms8g` as per [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html):

> -Xmssize
>
> Sets the initial size (in bytes) of the heap. This value must be a multiple of 1024 and greater than 1 MB. Append the letter k or K to indicate kilobytes, m or M to indicate megabytes, g or G to indicate gigabytes.